# Hadoop many Mappers

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Can one Job have several Mappers at the same time?

e.g.

```
    job.setMapperClass(Mapper1.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Mapper2.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Mapper3.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use [`ChainMapper`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainMapper.html). In fact, `ChainMapper` and [`ChainReducer`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainReducer.html) together enable to you execute MapReduce workflows of the form `Mapper+ | Reducer | Mapper*`.

Comment: what about these Mappers are independent and not a chain. It is like for the same input have 3 different Mappers?

Comment: +1 Jason

@user2597504, Then you run three different jobs having the same input.